# Getting "Runtime Exception" while launching Application with Fragments

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am new to **Android** and very new to **Fragments**.
I am trying to implement one sample **Fragments** application using some online sites guidance.

While i am implementing a sample Fragment application i am getting *RunTimeException* while launching my application in Emulator.

**Comeplete Exception** stack is shown below ::

```
    04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentex/com.example.fragmentex.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class fragment
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at com.example.fragmentex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     ... 11 more
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     ... 21 more
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne" on path: /data/app/com.example.fragmentex-2.apk
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
04-01 03:24:19.193: E/AndroidRuntime(1374):     ... 24 more
```

My android code is:

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.fragmentex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
        Fragment fr;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.bFrag2)) {
            fr = new FragmentTwo();

        } else {
            fr = new FragmentOne();
        }

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFrag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bFrag2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Fragment 2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.84" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fragmentex"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fragmentex.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**FragmentOne.java**

```
package com.example.fragmentex;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                   //Inflate the layout for this fragment

              return inflater.inflate(
                      R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
           }  

}
```

**New Log**

```
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.example.fragmentex.FragmentTwo.onCreateView(FragmentTwo.java:16)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  ... 22 more
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a ColorStateList (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f060001 a=-1 r=0x7f060001}
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2074)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:342)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:904)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:578)
04-02 10:13:07.143: E/AndroidRuntime(849):  ... 25 more
```

**FragmentTwo.Java**

```
package com.example.fragmentex;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                   //Inflate the layout for this fragment

              return inflater.inflate(
                      R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
           }  

}
```

**fragment_two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am in Fragment 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@style/AppTheme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your `FragmentOne` class ?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne" on path: /data/app/com.example.fragmentex-2.apk` is your meaningful error message so that is the class you need to post the source for.

Comment: what is your Emulator version,you are implementing fragment for above api 10 and you testing on below api 11.either test on from 11 and above api or use support v4 fragment.

Comment: @RaviKant : My Emulator version is 17(4.2.2)

Comment: @YeLinAung :: FragmentOne.java added

Comment: @Krishna change your package name in the xml file. check the answer!

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille : Yes you are correct.I done changes as per you instructions. Now Exp is not occurring but out put is not coming as per my expectation.

Comment: whats your expectation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Your package name reads:

```
com.example.fragmentex
```

Are you sure that your fragment is in the package:

```
com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest
```

Check where the FragmentOne class exists and copy the package name and then mention it in the xml file.

**Option 2:**

Try changing the Activity to FragmentActivity

that is `extends FragmentActivity`

**EDIT:**

change this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.84" />
```

to

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentex.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.84" />
```

**EDIT:** [for the second Exception, Resource not found]

change :

```
android:textColor="@style/AppTheme"
```

to:

```
style="@style/AppTheme" -> if you want to set the style to the textView
```

or

```
android:textColor = "@color/your_defined_color" - > if you want to set the color to the textView
```

Comment: Now it's showing Fragment but it is crashing while clicking on Frag2 button.04-01 14:45:03.232: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 14:45:03.232: E/AndroidRuntime(3163): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-01 14:45:03.232: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

04-01 14:45:03.232: E/AndroidRuntime(3163):  at com.example.fragmentex.FragmentTwo.onCreateView(FragmentTwo.java:16)

Comment: this is not the entire crash log. try posting the entire crash log in your question as an edit.

Comment: :: New log added at bottom of the query

Comment: post also fragment two xml and fragment two class thanks @Krishna

Comment: fragment_two.xml and FragmentTwo.java added. @Rat-a-tat

Answer (score 0):

For what it seems your `FragmentOne` class is not proper.

**make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

public FragmentOne() { <--- Add this
}

...
```

}

Comment: FragmentOne.java Added please check once

Comment: You haven't defined empty constructor

Comment: need to add in FragmentTWo also?

Comment: Yes, always add default empty constructor in your Fragments